# readline skips first line in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, readline

I've got a problem with a `for` loop that skips the first line. I know why but I don't know how to fix it. And when I change it to a `while` loop, or in a matter of fact in to anything, it gives me an error:

```
line 29, in <module>
    worksheet.write(row, col, float(b))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

The code is:

```
import xlsxwriter
import tkinter

file_list = []
x = 1
while x <= 30:
    file_list.append('AuF7_PATP 10_5M_MgF2_20µl_1s_S' + str(x) + '_calibrated.txt')
    x+=1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_list[0]+'.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 1
col = 0
f = open(file_list[0], 'r')
for line in f:
    a = f.readline()
    b = a[0:(a.rfind("\t"))]
    c = a[(a.rfind("\t")):-1]
    worksheet.write(row, col, float(b))
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, float(c))
    row += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looping over the file **already** reads lines. You don't need nor should you call `f.readline()` again. You already have the line in `line`, so just use that.

Moreover, you appear to have tab-separated data; consider using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to split your rows; it can also convert your data to floats for you:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
for row, (b, c) in enumerate(reader, 1):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, b)
    worksheet.write(row, 1, c)
```

The above uses `enumerate()` to give you a counter per data row as well. The `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` quoting option causes anything not in quotes in your input file to be auto-converted to `float` objects.

Comment: Thank You very much, You were great help :) I didn't even know the module csv.reader ! 
Cheers
Peter